# deploy already installed application on WebLogic 10.3.4 using wlfullclient.jar

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g

I have an application named `HelloWorld` installed, yet not deployed. Its state is `Installed`, like such:

[image]

When I'm trying to deploy it on target server, say `AdminServer`, it results in **creating a new application named** `helloworld.war` **which is deployed on** `AdminServer` whereas the original `HelloWorld` app remains in `Installed` state. App `helloworld.war` is the one that is in state `Active`... Snapshot:

[image]

Here's the code I use to deploy the already installed app:

```
File warFilePath = new File("c:/helloworld.war"); // war file path on AdminServer machine

Target adminServerTarget = deployManager.getTarget("AdminServer");
WebLogicTargetModuleID targetModuleID = deployManager.createTargetModuleID(
        "HelloWorld", ModuleType.WAR, adminServerTarget);
WebLogicTargetModuleID[] targetModuleIDs = new WebLogicTargetModuleID[1];
targetModuleIDs[0] = targetModuleID;

ProgressObject redeployProcessObject =
    deployManager.redeploy(targetModuleIDs, warFilePath, null /*no deployment plan*/ );
```

There are two surprising facts, though.

First, when running this code on WebLogic versions 9.x to 10.3.**3** it works great.

Second, when running this code from WLST prompt, with **jython** it also works great even on version 10.3.**4** (I can attach the exact commands although they're the same as java except for syntactic adoptions)...

My question is, how do I make it work also on 10.3.4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have thought that no one would answer this question... :)

Anyway, I found a solution. I should have used `deploy` instead of `redeploy`, with a `DeploymentOptions` of which name is the existing application name (`HelloWorld`):

```
      ProgressObject redeployProcessObject = null;
      try {
          final DeploymentOptions options = new DeploymentOptions();
          options.setName(applicationName);
          redeployProcessObject = deployManager.deploy(
              targetModuleIDs, warFilePath, null /*no deployment plan*/, options);
      } catch (TargetException e) {
          final String message =
                  String.format("Deployment of application %s on target %s failed: %s",
                          applicationName, allTargets, e.getMessage());
          _log.error(message, e);
      }
```

According to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23549_01/apirefs.1111/e13941/weblogic/deploy/api/spi/WebLogicDeploymentManager.html), `redeploy` only replaces the current application files and plan with an updated version. Whereas `deploy` distributes the files (from the AdminServer) to the target(s) and starts the application.

Also, after digging deep in WebLogic's jython scripts and jars I found out that this is exactly what's done when invoking `redeploy` in the WLST.